# Convert array of strings with single quotes to array of strings with double quotes

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of strings, where each string in the list can either start with a single or double quote, such as:

```
my_list = ['a string with a single quote', "my organisation's goals", 'another string with double quote']
```

Notice that the string that contains double quotes is as such because it contains an apostrophe.

How can I make sure that my list contains each string within a double quote? In other words, I'd like for `my_list` to be:

```
my_list = ["a string with a single quote", "my organisation's goals", "another string with double quote"]
```

I've tried to simply use `.replace("'", '"')`, but this doesn't work because it will replace the apostrophe with a double quote, which causes undesired behavior.

I've also tried something like this, but similar to the above, it doesn't work.

```
new_list = [item[1:-1] if item.startswith("'") and item.endswith("'") else item for item in my_list]
```

Comment: The internal Python representation of your list should be the same whether you define it using single or double apostrophe strings.

Comment: I understand that, but I would like to make this change for database reasons.

Comment: The single and double quotes are not part of the literal string and neither should be persisted to your database tables.

Comment: I am doing other things prior to saving my data into the database, where the above `my_list` causes an issue.

Comment: As already stated: the quotes you see are only the way Python shows you the strings when you `print` the list, they are **not** part of the data. If you encounter any problem due to the *representation* Python uses when *printing* the list, then you are doing something very wrong. Please clarify the way you are using the data from the lists in your code.

Comment: I am doing `JSON.parse()` on the client side after retrieving the data and if the data that is saved, which in this case would be a string representation of the list, contains single quotes, it throws an error because JSON data cannot contain single quotes.

Comment: How are you sending the data to the client? If you just use `json.dumps(string)` it should envolve every string in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use `json.dumps()`:

```
import json
my_list = ['a string with a single quote', "my organisation's goals", 'another string with double quote']
my_new_list = json.dumps(my_list)

print(my_new_list)
```

Comment: This fails for characters with codepoints higher than U+FFFF, like emoji, e.g. . `['\U0001f345']` -> `["\ud83c\udf45"]` (which is UTF-16, IIRC).

Answer (score -1):

Overkill but gets the job done.

```py
class CustomRepr:
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.str = str

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'"{self.str}"'

my_list = ['a string with a single quote', "my organisation's goals", 'another string with double quote']


my_list2 = [CustomRepr(str) for str in my_list]

print(my_list2)
```

Comment: If any of the strings contain a double-quote, this produces invalid output.